# Executing a series of functions with parameters in gulp

Tags: gulp

I encounter an error trying to execute a bunch of custom functions in gulp.

My code looks like this:

```js
function subsiteCss(subsite) {

    return gulp
        .src(path.join(paths.src, `scss/styles-${subsite}.scss`))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ sourceMap: true, outputStyle: 'expanded', 'includePaths': ['node_modules/sass-mq', '../node_modules/sass-mq'] }))
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe(postcss([cssnano()]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sassSubsitesDist))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function subsiteAllCss() {
    gulp.parallel(subsiteCss('subsite-1'), subsiteCss('subsite-2'), subsiteCss('subsite-3'));
}
```

the function `subsiteCss(subsite)` is working fine if I hardcode the parameter. But when I want to execute `subsiteAllCss` like this:

```js
const build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(subsiteAllCss, css, js, headScripts), svg, copyFonts);
```

I get the error: `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: [object Object]`
It works if I remove `subsiteAllCss` from `gulp.parallel(...)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`gulp.parallel` expects its arguments to be streams. Change your definition of `subsiteAllCss` to make it a stream instead of a function that returns void:

```js
var subsiteAllCss = gulp.parallel(subsiteCss('subsite-1'), subsiteCss('subsite-2'), subsiteCss('subsite-3'));
```